# How to detect if child has collided with specific parent's color on Unity UI Image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have generated Maze, but it is not a set of objects (walls), but a texture. So I want to Log messages when this texture's child (green rectangle) has collided with a black wall, how do I do that? Thank you!

[Maze texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5cs.png)

[Parent & child in root view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljdJX.png)

Comment: If the maze is not random, you could set a polygon 2D collider to it. Else you’d go into checking if the green dot is over a black pixel.

Comment: @Everts it is generated randomly

Comment: Then solution 2. Take the 4 corners of the green dot and check if their position is over a black pixel on the map. If so, you got a collision. Since it appears a black section is always at least the size of the green dot, it will be fine.